# Problema con decimales en ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una administración de pagos en la cual tengo un error que no podido solucionar hasta el momento. El error se da en el valor monetario del pago pues sea el valor que se ingrese en la vista me genera un dato decimal del tipo xxxx.00. Es decir si tipeo el valor 5.60 me regresa el valor 560.00, si pongo 40.60 me regresa 4060.00 etc.

El codigo que uso es el siguiente

**Model**

```
[Column, Display(Name = "Valor"), Required, DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal valor { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.valor, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.valor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @step = "0.01"} })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.valor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            Proyecto proy = r.proyectos.Single(i => i.id == Global.idProyectoActual);
            Pago pago = new Pago();
            pago.valor = Convert.ToDecimal(collection["valor"].ToString());
            pago.factura = collection["factura"];
            pago.idProyecto = Global.idProyectoActual;
            pago.fechaRegistro = DateTime.Now;
            r.pagos.InsertOnSubmit(pago);

            proy.valorRestante = proy.valorRestante - pago.valor;

            r.SubmitChanges();
            return Redirect("~/Proyecto/Details/"+Global.idProyectoActual);
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Es necesario aclarar que el error surge en el metodo post ActionResult solamente, pues si cargo directamente en la base un valor por ejemplo 20.10 ese dato aparece si ningun problema en las tablas de las vistas (generalmente Index) asi como en la vista de modificacion (generalmente Edit).

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia, pero no surge efecto el cambio, sigo teniendo el mismo error detallado

Comment: El error viene puesto que en la cultura definida tiene el . como separador de miles y la , como separador de decimales. Si introduces 40,60 seguramente te lo convierta correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Con el formato `{0:F2}` estás forzando a que se ponga un punto decimal y al final doble cero, es por eso que se te muestra esos resultados.

Para corregirlo deberás cambiarlo por `{0:C}` o en su caso, usa `{C}`, de esta forma, te va a respetar el formato y a ponerlo como formato moneda. Por ejemplo, para el valor 40.60, obtendrás `$40.60`. La anotación finalmente quedaría:

```
[Column, Display(Name = "Valor"), Required, DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal valor { get; set; }
```

Aquí podrás ver la [demostración](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5aYEK8) y el resultado.

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia, pero el error solo da en el metodo post de Create, es decir en el llamado de datos como planteas el ejemplo del link no se produce el error

Answer (score 0):

Estoy haciendo pruebas y veo que al Action llega el valor correcto. Las "," están des habilitadas para su ingreso en el input por lo que formato no es. De hecho estoy simulando el parseo que utilizas en esta línea:

```
Convert.ToDecimal(collection["valor"].ToString());
```

y tampoco tuve problemas. Es más, ese parseo es innecesario ya que llega al Action con el tipo de dato correcto (decimal). Para el POST utilicé:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/Create",
        data: $("form").serialize()
    });
```

En la vista lo único que agregue fue un tag form que engloba tu vista y un evento onSubmit que llama al ajax que detallo arriba. 
Quizás es el POST que estas realizando... cómo lo estás haciendo?